# Developing dynamic code

Tags: c#

I'm having a dynamic columns.

I want to make a PDF file (with iTextSharp) with table-column 3.

I need a code so that for if I'm having 5 columns, then

- 1st row - 3 columns (having data)
- 2nd row - 2 columns (having data) + last column (no data)

```
 for (int i = 0; i < col_count; i++)
        {  
            tablepg1.AddCell(new Phrase(Companies[i], companiesH));
            j++;
            if (j > 2)
            {
                j = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                {
                    tablepg1.AddCell(ClipImpageProcess(chartnameLIST[tablecount], 8, writer));
                    tablecount++;
                }
            }

        }
        if ((col_count % 3) != 0)
        {
            int num_empty_cells = 3 - (col_count % 3);
            for (int i = 0; i < num_empty_cells; i++)
            {
                tablepg1.AddCell("");
            }
        }
```

`Companies[i]` - has the data
`X` - represent blank cell

Comment: And? What is your issue?

Comment: for itextsharp if 3 col are stated, then i should add data in multiples of 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill the table with all the columns with data, and in the end add 0, 1 or 2 `"X"` cell(s) :

```
for (int i = 0; i < col_count; i++) {
    tablepg1.AddCell(new Phrase(Companies[i], companiesH));
}

if ((col_count % 3) != 0) {
    int num_empty_cells = 3 - (col_count % 3);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_empty_cells) {
        tablepg1.AddCell("X"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thnks also. my mind was freezed for that!!

Comment: i have edited the code , still for the last row addcell-clipimage, last row of the images are not getting displayed